# Ellipse curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, conic-sections

> Let $a,b>0$ and let $\alpha$ be the ellipse
> $\alpha(t)=\big(x(t),y(t)\big)=\big( a\cos t, b\sin t\big)$.
>
> Let $(u(t),0)$ be the point where the line through $\alpha(t)$
> perpendicular to $\alpha'(t)$ meets the $x$-axis, and let $d(t)$ be
> the distance between $\alpha(t)$ and $(u(t),0)$.
> Find a formula for $\kappa(t)$ in terms of $a$, $b$ and $d(t)$.

The curvature of the ellipse has been discussed thoroughly in this question: [how to calculate the curvature of an ellipse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527538/how-to-calculate-the-curvature-of-an-ellipse)

However, I can't find a way to use $d(t)$ in expressing curvature.

I tried to sketch the graph and realized that I can inscribe a circle inside the ellipse. But that is as far as I can go.

[image: Sketch graph]

I also tried to explicitly write out $d(t)$, but it gives me an ugly expression.

Comment: What did you get for $d(t)$? You shold recognize some similar part as in $\kappa(t)$.

Comment: I found that I made a calculation error. That is the reason that I am getting weird values and unable to recognize the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

**Equation of tangent**

$$0=T(x,y)\equiv \frac{x\cos t}{a}+\frac{y\sin  t}{b}-1$$

**Equation of normal**

$$0=N(x,y) \equiv \frac{ax}{\cos t}-\frac{by}{\sin t}-(a^2-b^2)$$

Note that $N(u,0)=0$ and

\begin{align}
  u(t) &= \frac{(a^2-b^2)\cos t}{a} \\
  d(t) &= \frac{|T(u,0)|}{\sqrt{\dfrac{\cos^2 t}{a^2}+\dfrac{\sin^2 t}{b^2}}} \\
  &= \frac{\left| -\sin^2 t-\dfrac{b^2\cos^2 t}{a^2} \right|}
          {\sqrt{\dfrac{\cos^2 t}{a^2}+\dfrac{\sin^2 t}{b^2}}} \\
  &= b^2\sqrt{\frac{\cos^2 t}{a^2}+\frac{\sin^2 t}{b^2}} \\
  \kappa &= \frac{1}{a^2 b^2
  \left(
    \dfrac{\cos^2 t}{a^2}+\dfrac{\sin^2 t}{b^2}
  \right)^{3/2}} \\
  &= \frac{b^4}{a^2 d^3}
\end{align}

Comment: Could you explain how you got the formula for the distance?

Comment: The distance of a point $(x',y')$ from the line $Ax+By+C=0$ is given by
$$\left| \frac{Ax'+By'+C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} \right|$$ and see the $3$D analogy in another post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2104970/perpendicular-distance-from-origin-to-the-triangle/2105004#2105004).

Comment: I guess what I meant is why is the distance between $\alpha(t)$ and $(u(t), 0)$ the same thing as the distance between the tangent and $(u(t), 0)$.

Comment: Back to your post, $\alpha$ is the curve, $\alpha'$ is the tangent line, i.e. $T=0$.  A line through $\alpha$ and perpendicular to $\alpha'$ is the normal through $\vec{r}=\alpha(t)$, i.e. $N=0$.  The line cut the $x$-axis at $(u,0) \implies N(u,0)=0$.

Comment: Why is $\alpha'$ the tangent line? It looks different from $T(x,y)$

Comment: Strictly speaking, $\alpha'(t)$ is a tangent vector.  In the language of vectors, tangent line should be $\vec{r}(\lambda;t)=\alpha(t)+\lambda \alpha'(t)$, whereas in coordinate geometry it reads $T(x,y)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

[It is well known that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3455731/curvature-calculation-of-the-ellipse-at-the-end-of-its-axes/3457101#3457101) (see figure below, $F$ and $G$ are the foci):

$$
\kappa={\cos\alpha\over2}\left({1\over p}+{1\over q}\right)
={a\cos\alpha\over pq}.
$$
On the other hand, from the formula for the length of a bisector we get:
$$
d^2={b^2\over a^2}pq
$$
while from the cosine rule applied to triangle $FPG$ we obtain
$$
\cos^2\alpha={b^2\over pq}.
$$
Inserting these results into the formula for $\kappa$ we finally get:
$$
\kappa={b^4\over a^2d^3}.
$$

[image]